# I have a problem with my cors when using the latest version of socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I was wondering if someone could help me adapt my code to the latest version of socket.io. I have already tried to implement the new features but im still not able to console log anything in my terminal, can anyone see the problem? This is the error I get when I try and console log name and room in the backend after refreshing my frontend:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NOaiiEq' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

frontend code:

````
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import queryString from "query-string";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";



const Chat = () => { 
     let location = useLocation();
const [ name, setName ] = useState('');
const [ room, setRoom ] = useState('');
const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:3000/chat';
 
useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search)

 const socket = io(ENDPOINT); 
  
    setName(name);
    setRoom(room); 

    socket.emit('join', { name, room });

}, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);

    return(  
        <h1>Chat</h1>
    )
}
export default Chat;
    
    ```
    
    backend code: 
    
    ```
    require("dotenv").config();
    
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const server = require('http').createServer(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
      cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        allowHeaders: ['x-secret-token'],
        credentials: true
      }
    });
    
    
    
    
    const client = require("./client");
    
    // Run when a client connects
    
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log('We have a new connection!');
    
      socket.on('join', ({ name, room }) => {
           console.log(name, room);
      });
    
      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User has left!');
      })
    });
    
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // app.use(express.json)
    const cors = require("cors");
    app.use(cors({
        exposedHeaders: 'x-secret-token',
      }))
    
    //Routers
    
    const registerRouter = require("./Routes/Register");
    app.use("/register", registerRouter);
    
    const loginRouter = require("./Routes/Login");
    app.use("/login", loginRouter);
    
    
    const booksRouter = require("./Routes/Books");
    app.use("/books", booksRouter)
    
    const chat = require("./Routes/Chat");
    app.use("/chat", chat); 
    
    
    
    //Build server
    app.set("port", process.env.port || 3000);
    
    
    
    
    //Start server
    server.listen(app.get("port"), (server) => {
        console.info(`Server listen on port ${app.get("port")}`);
    });
````

I also tried to add the client side code that socket.io recommended which looks like this:

```
    // client-side
    const io = require("socket.io-client");
    const socket = io("https://api.example.com", {
      withCredentials: true,
      extraHeaders: {
        "my-custom-header": "abcd"
      }
    });
```

But this didnt work- any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.Hope it works. Goodluck!

Frontend:
const io = require("socket.io-client");
// import io from "socket.io-client"; same as above require module

const socket = io("localhost:3001", {
withCredentials: true,
extraHeaders: {
"my-custom-header": "text/plain"
}
});